# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

When i am running below JavaScript, I am getting:

> (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did
>   not return a result set)

JavaScript:

```
var connection = new Packages.SQLConnection("mssql");
connection.connect("Servername.com", 1433, "DBEvents","Username","Password");

var results = connection.getResults("exec GetDealsSequence_Perftest");
```

Comment: Is this for Java or JavaScript? Your tags and the code sample contradict each other.

Comment: What library are you using for executing this? If this `Packages.SQLConnection` is your own code, then please include it in your question. The main problem is that this library (or your own code) is calling JDBCs `Statement.executeQuery` for something that doesn't produce a result set or produces multiple results (update counts and one or more result sets), in which case the correct way to execute is using `Statement.execute` instead (and iterate over the multiple results).